# Infinite loop in merge sort?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, infinite-loop

I have no idea what is happening here. This merge sort algorithm has worked with many different types of inputs before. I've now tried it with my "corruption" variable and it's not working. Please help!

My code:

```
private void mergeWithCorruption(MyNode[] left, MyNode[] right, MyNode[] output) {
    int l = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int o = 0;
    while (l < left.length && r < right.length) {
        if (left[l].getCorruption() == right[r].getCorruption()) {
            // If left == right, add left
            output[o] = left[l];
            l++;
            o++;
        } else if (left[l].getCorruption() < right[r].getCorruption()) {
            // Left is less than right. Add left to output
            output[o] = left[l];
            l++;
            o++;
        } else if (left[l].getCorruption() > right[r].getCorruption()) {
            // Left is greater than right. Add right to output
            output[o] = right[r];
            r++;
            o++;
        }
        System.out.println("l == " + l);
        System.out.println("r == " + r);
        System.out.println(left[0].getCorruption() + " - " + right[0].getCorruption());
    }
    // Finish off the left if there is some remaining
    while (l < left.length) {
        output[o] = left[l];
        o++;
        l++;
    }
    // Finish off the right if there is some remaining
    while (r < right.length) {
        output[o] = right[r];
        o++;
        r++;
    }
}

public void sortByCorruption(MyNode[] arr) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        int halfSize = arr.length / 2;
        MyNode[] left = new MyNode[halfSize];
        MyNode[] right = new MyNode[arr.length - halfSize];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, left, 0, halfSize);
        System.arraycopy(arr, halfSize, right, 0, arr.length - halfSize);

        sortByCorruption(left);
        sortByCorruption(right);

        mergeWithCorruption(left, right, arr);
    }
}
```

My infinite logging (I've pinpointed where it is looping):

```
l == 0
r == 0
0.528928883 - 0.528928883
l == 0
r == 0
0.528928883 - 0.528928883
etc...
```

Why is it looping? Those two doubles clearly equal each other, so why isn't it entering into the above 'if' statement??

Comment: Probably a floating point precision problem wherein they don't quite evaluate to equal.

Comment: Gotcha. So do you think I should just round it to some arbitrary number of decimals places?

Comment: Instead of testing if a == b test if abs(a-b) <= some small epsilon. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I'll check that out as well. I added a .floatValue() modifier after .getCorruption() and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Can't you just rearrange the conditions to have: `if <`, `else if >`, `else` ? There would be no need for equality test.